# SQL query problem

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am fetching some data from a table. Suppose my query is like this

```
select ename from emp where job="clerk"
```

This is returning duplicate ename too but in order in which they have entered.

I modified this to

```
select distinct ename from emp where job="clerk"
```

I did this to avoid duplicate values.But ename are coming in alphabetically ascending order. But i want this in the order in which i have entered data as it was coming without using distinct.

Comment: Which DB are you using? For example, in Oracle the order is not automatically alphabetically ascending just by using DISTINCT.

Answer (score 3):

Data in SQL tables have no inherent order. If you want an order, you have to specify it using `ORDER BY`. If you use `DISTINCT`, you can only order by columns that you select!

If you have a PK, this would be an approximation:

```
select distinct id,ename from emp where job="clerk" order by id desc
```

From an older [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883247/insert-row-in-proper-order-on-table-based-off-of-primary-key/6883847#6883847) (I knew this would be helpful):

> Unless you specify ORDER BY, there are no guarantees about what rows
>   will be returned first.
>
> But in practice, the order will typically match the clustered index
>   order, and will not vary between calls. Don't rely on this behaviour.

[Does MySQL's LIMIT keyword guarantee order of returned data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023675/does-mysqls-limit-keyword-guarantee-order-of-returned-data)

> There is no default sort order. Even if the table has a clustered
>   index, you are not guaranteed to get the results in that order. You
>   must use an order by clause if you want a specific order.

[SQL best practice to deal with default sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order)

....

Comment: You can order by any column on the table, it doesn't have to be in your select clause

Comment: If you don't use DISTINCT, yes. If you use distinct, how do you want to order by a column you didn't include into your select? There may be multiple "order-by-values" for the same distinct value.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say i am using sqlite and when i am using distinct it is coming in alphabetically ascending order like ename having A is coming first,having B coming second and so on. I dont want any order.I want the data in the order in which they exist in database.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has auto_increment key (id), you can try this:

```
SELECT ename FROM emp WHERE job="clerk" GROUP BY ename ORDER BY id
```